# What's wrong with my syntax?

Tags: java, android, syntax

Eclipse is giving me many errors for one specific line of code says:

Multiple markers at this line

```
- Syntax error, insert ")" to complete 
 ConstructorDeclaration
- Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody
- Syntax error, insert ";" to complete 
 ConstructorDeclaration
- Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
- Syntax error, insert ")" to complete 
 MethodInvocation
```

The line is:

```
setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(); {
```

and on a different line i get errors

Multiple markers at this line

```
- Syntax error on token ")", delete 
 this token
- Syntax error on token "(", ; expected
```

for line: public void onClick(View v); {

Heres activity2.java:

```
package android.app;
import android.app.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;



public class activity2 extends Activity{

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);

        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Back);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
            }
            Button sound = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sound);
            setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(); {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v); {
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(TestSonido.this, R.raw.whippingsound);  
                    mp.start();
                }
            }
            ;

    ;
}}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do there? Perhaps you want to get rid of the semicolon by changing `View.OnClickListener(); {` to `View.OnClickListener() {` You're also missing the closing parenthesis. You need to count opening and closing parenthesis to be sure that they match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
            setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(); {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v); {
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(TestSonido.this, R.raw.whippingsound);  
                    mp.start();
                }
            }
```

should be this:

```
            setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(TestSonido.this, R.raw.whippingsound);  
                    mp.start();
                }
            })
```

(no semicolon before the contents of the inner class; and, yes right-parenthesis at end of function call).

Comment: You will need a semicolon to end the statement.

Comment: @I82Much: There is one. (That semicolon is on a separate line in the original code, so I left it there.)

Comment: setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { is still requesting semi colon??  @ruakh

Answer (score 2):

```
setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(); {
```

=>

```
setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```